# In nodeMailer, where is the transport object created

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, contact-form, nodemailer

This is a simple question. I have an app created using Node.JS. I am trying to follow the instructions at [nodeMailer](https://nodemailer.com/about/) to create a mailer to use for a contact form in my index.html file. I have already installed nodemailer into my node_modules folder (`$npm install nodemailer --save`) and I am using Node.JS v6.10. The instructions then say to "create a transport object" and gives a sample of the transport object code. Where (specifically, in what file) do I create this transport object (in other words, where does this code go?)? Or do I create a new file (and if so, under what folder)? Below is a screenshot of my app directory. Can someone point me to where I am suppose to place the code for the transport object?

[image]

Comment: Edit: there are a lot of places it can go, it just depends on what works best for you. Do you have a separate file for your routes?

Comment: nodemailer can't be used in client side, if you have routes or wherever you send your requests try using the sample there. Node modules directory is not meant to be used for your files in the way that it seems to you think only as a folder that holds all libraries which you should not manually add/edit/delete files